# absolut size for image in mobile device and website css

Tags: css, mobile, size

ive got a picture that must be in the same size on website and on mobile device.

I configured that css :

```
.my-pic {
width: 2.5cm!important; 
height: 4.5cm!important;}
```

for this html :

```
<img src='/path/to/img.png' class='my-pic'/>
```

I measured the pic on my website and it's in right size . but on mobile its smaller (1.5cm on 4 cm)

How can I handle that issue ?

Comment: Does your website use the correct `<meta>` viewport, to ensure that mobile devices do not render it zoomed out?  That may account for the difference in size if your CSS has the dimensions fixed.

Comment: my viewport is : content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"

Comment: Is this happening on multiple mobile devices, or just iOS safari?  If the latter you could try adding `shrink-to-fit=no` to your `<meta>`.  My default (even with `width=device-width` Safari will scale the page down to fit content that is wider than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries, and set the css as per requirement